# Android device as a continuous barcode scanner for PC

Tags: android, tcp, udp, barcode-scanner

I would like to have barcode scanner functionality in my application written for PC. The idea was to take a standard device not forcing the user to buy any extra equipment.

So I built an ZXing based application. Unfortunately capabilities of a built-in webcam are not sufficient to read barcodes reliably. Camera focuses on objects in 50cm-1m distance. From this distance majority of barcodes are too small for webcam resolution. If I bring barcode closer to the camera filling the whole image field, resolution is enough to recognize barcodes but barcode is blurred because is out of focus.

Are there some ready to use Andriod applications that have continuous scanning mode and can send barcode immediately after scanning? scan-send-scan-send-scan-send-scan-send-scan-send until I stop it. Thansfer protocol is irrelevant: could be HTTP or UDP.

I found some applications, but they either cannot send barcodes or I should do some manipulations to send a scanned barcode or I am allowed to scan in continuous mode without sending and then do some manipulations in order to send these multiple barcodes. Or they are commercial products requiring me to install their server part on a PC, and this server part does keyboard emulation. I would like to have a separate communication channel that emulates nothing and is on its own, so that I could take for example Delphi Indy components to receive data.

Comment: Reminder that there is a [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android) site.

Comment: This is a dead site. Nobody is visiting it

Comment: Not sure if you found https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded.git and investigate the sample app to see if it can be adapted to fit your needs.